# Front end private messaging plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm looking everywhere for a private messaging plugin for wordpress.

Specifically for the front end, I'm not interested in allowing users to access the wp-admin.

Moreso, i don't want them knowing i'm using wordpress.

Any plugin that allows one user to contact another would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: buddypress allow private and public messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin,

http://wordpress.org/plugins/private-messages-for-wordpress/

And more plugins see the list of private messaging plugins,

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/private-message